# SQL insert syntax error in vba code

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, insert

Can some one help me format this string correctly so that my SQL code will execute when the button command is executed? I'm new to visual basic and not sure where I am messing this part up or if I can even include the Access controls in my query.

Here is the code I am attempting to execute:

```
Private Sub new_record_btn_Click()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sSQL As String

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection

RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblHydro( [Mine ID], [Facility], [Status], [Commodity], [Is   Mine Currently Below Water Table (3/10/07)?] ) SELECT tblMine.MineID, tblMine.MineName, tblMine.Status, tblMineAcreage.CommodityType, tblPermits.GWImpact FROM (tblMine INNER JOIN tblPermits ON tblMine.MineID = tblPermits.MineID) INNER JOIN tblMineAcreage ON (tblPermits.PermitID = tblMineAcreage.PermitID) AND (tblMine.MineID = tblMineAcreage.MineID) WHERE 'Forms!frmHydroNEW.MineID' = tblHydro.[Mine ID]"
conn.Execute sSQL
frmHydroSub.Requery
End Sub
```

I get a syntax error from the above

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about this at all.... :(

any help is much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using:

```
Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute sSQL
```

So

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblHydro ( [Mine ID], [Facility], [Status], " _
& "[Commodity], [Is   Mine Currently Below Water Table (3/10/07)?] ) " _
& "SELECT tblMine.MineID, tblMine.MineName, tblMine.Status, " _
& "tblMineAcreage.CommodityType, tblPermits.GWImpact " _
& "FROM (tblMine INNER JOIN tblPermits ON tblMine.MineID = tblPermits.MineID) " _
& "INNER JOIN tblMineAcreage ON (tblPermits.PermitID = tblMineAcreage.PermitID) " _
& "AND (tblMine.MineID = tblMineAcreage.MineID) " _
& "WHERE tblHydro.[Mine ID]=" &  Forms!frmHydroNEW.MineID

''Or possibly Me.MineID, depending on where the code is running

db.Execute sSQL
```

However, `[Is   Mine Currently Below Water Table (3/10/07)?]` is a very odd field name, if it is a parameter, you need more work.

A form cannot be reference in that way in VBA, it must be outside the quotes so a value is returned, not a reference to the form. Note also that the form must be open.

Comment: my bad on the typo, however i am getting an error still, "No value given for one or more required parameters." Debug is highlighting conn.execute part

Comment: Debug will always highlight any Execute if the SQL is incorrect.

Comment: I'm new to vb so if you could explain to me what is going on with the underscores and ampersands around my select statement items that would be helpful as well

Comment: The ampersand is a string concatenator, the underscore is a line continuation character. It just makes a string easier to read. I suspect your main problem is that you have a parameter `[Is Mine Currently Below Water Table (3/10/07)?]` and that will not work in VBA.

Comment: Ok I see that now, i changed that long name to [Currently In GW] but still getting same "no value given" error, I wonder if the problem now is referencing the access controls in the where clause of the sql?

Comment: Quite likely. It is often a good idea to Debug.Print sSQL and paste into a query design window, sql view, to see if the SQL is good.

Comment: @Remou, why not consolidate the 3 lines of code down to `CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO ...."`

Comment: @Linger Because it is easier to debug if the sql is a separate statement, also neater. Furthermore, each instance of CurrentDB is a new instance, so you cannot get RecordsAffected from CurrentDB.

Comment: You can use DoCmd.OpenFor, you can use `CurrentProject.AllForms("formname").IsLoaded Then` note that the form must exist. Are you sure you need the form?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of that. I'm still stuck on the syntax for the SQL. i think the bigger problem might be some conditional thing in the statement, mostly that the MineID doesn't exist in the table before the command is executed so its getting confused there. Somehow when I make new records int his form the MineiD is getting in to the tblHydro but I think that is because parent and child forms are linked on that field. What I would want _i think_ is to insert for the active record in the subform, but i'm too much of a noob to do that so far

Comment: Where are you running the code, form or subform? Is [Currently In GW] a field or a control? If you are only inserting one record, can you use multiple child / master or simple VBA?

Comment: I'm trying to run this in the subform, but I'm guessing that since you asked that may not be the best place to run from. So i tried the multiple links and that works but eh GUI only lets specify three, can i keep specifying them by text in the properties window?

Comment: Have you tried simply updating the controls in a suitable event? I am a little worried that your are duplicating data from the main table in a related table that does not need to be duplicated. If more than three fields are the same, why not just an ID?

Comment: jesus, you are right. I am going about this thing all wrong. An id IS EXACTLY what I should do instead. thank you and again, sorry for the confusion